# transferring a date from Knockoutjs to API gets me 01/01/0001

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api2, momentjs

I am doing a small project to learn `Knockoutjs` and I encountered a problem when transferring a `date` to the server.

Basically I have the following code :-

```
    self.loanBookSubmit = function (formElement) {
    var loannee = {
        BookId: this.loanedBook.Id,
        Date: ko.observable(moment(self.newLoanBook.CurrentDate()).format('DD-MM-YYYY')),
        Name: self.newLoanBook.Name(),
        Surname: self.newLoanBook.Surname(),
        Comments: self.newLoanBook.Comments()
    };

    console.log(loannee);

    ajaxHelper(loansUri, 'POST', loannee).done(function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        self.books.push(item);
    });
}
```

Now `console.log(loanee)`, the date is correct however when I transfer that to my api, I am getting a blank date `01/01/0001`.

Can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should try doing `ko.observable(new Date(moment(self.newLoanBook.CurrentDate()).format('DD-MM-YYYY')))`

Comment: ok I have solved it.  I mistakenly did Date instead of the actual name of the paramenter.  Also I needed to remove the ko.observable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

var loannee = {
        BookId: this.loanedBook.Id,
        Date: new Date(self.newLoanBook.CurrentDate().getFullYear(), self.newLoanBook.CurrentDate().getMonth() + 1, self.newLoanBook.CurrentDate().getDate()),
        Name: self.newLoanBook.Name(),
        Surname: self.newLoanBook.Surname(),
        Comments: self.newLoanBook.Comments()
    };

Answer (score 0):

The name of the variable had to be the same as the name of the parameter in the object and also ko.observable() needed to be removed.

So the correct syntax should be :-

```
         DateLoaned: moment(self.newLoanBook.DateLoaned()).format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
```